# Post request via jquery ajax in yii2, the data sent to backend but ajax runs the error func. instead of success func

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

This data i send works and stored in the db. But logging the data from success function don't work, instead it runs the error function which returns responseText = "OK" and status = 200 and it also run the alert() in the error function. I'm confused why?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/blog/web/pages/home/save",
    data: {data : data},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {

        //do something else
        console.log(err);
        if(err){
            alert('It works!');
        }

    }

});
```

This is my php yii2 actionSave function:

```
public function actionSave(){
    $model = new Users();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $model->name = $data["data"]["name"];
        $model->username = $data["data"]["username"];
        $model->password = $data["data"]["password"];
        $model->email = $data["data"]["email"];
        $model->save();
        return "OK";
    }
    else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: You not return any `error` message in your controller, as well as not showing what type of response you get. This question require more information to be provided.

Comment: get ajax data in controller with `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: Try to remove the line `dataType: "json",`. I'm not sure if it might be the cause for calling the error callback instead of success but you are telling jquery to expect the response in json format but `OK` is not a valid json.